# Get EXIF data from Image with ImageIO

Tags: ios, exif, error-code

in my app i want to read image metadata, from the ImagePickerController.
I tried this like this:

```
NSURL* imgURL = (NSURL *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
NSLog(@"%@", imgURL);

CGImageSourceRef mySourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)imgURL, NULL);
NSDictionary *myMetadata = (__bridge NSDictionary *) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(mySourceRef,0,NULL);

NSDictionary *exifDic = [myMetadata objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary];
NSDictionary *tiffDic = [myMetadata objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary];

NSLog(@"exifDic properties: %@", myMetadata); //all data
float rawShutterSpeed = [[exifDic objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifExposureTime] floatValue];
int decShutterSpeed = (1 / rawShutterSpeed);
NSLog(@"Camera %@",[tiffDic objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyTIFFModel]);
NSLog(@"Focal Length %@mm",[exifDic objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifFocalLength]);
NSLog(@"Shutter Speed %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1/%d", decShutterSpeed]);
NSLog(@"Aperture f/%@",[exifDic objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifFNumber]);
NSNumber *ExifISOSpeed  = [[exifDic objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifISOSpeedRatings] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"ISO %i",[ExifISOSpeed integerValue]);
NSLog(@"Taken %@",[exifDic objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeDigitized]);
```

But i get the ImageIO error:

> ImageIO:   CGImageSourceCreateWithURL CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource failed with error code -11.

I didn't find a documentation about error code -11, only about -15 (bad param).
I hope you'll have a solution.

Greets
s4lfish

Comment: I now use ALAssets to get metadata from an image. I will post the solution after these 8h of waiting. But feel free to delete this thread, because my solution doesn't really answer the ImageIO question, since it's another way of getting the metadata.